# Is there a Trash explorer to explore and restore .Trash-$uid contents?

Tags: data-recovery, trash

I work with external storage and mounts a lot, and I often end up with a `.Trash` directory somewhere, whose contents are not shown in the File Manager trash bin, even though `.Trash/files` contains a lot of files.

The whole hierarchy in `.Trash/files` is changed compared to the original parent directory, and a lot of files appear to have duplicates. So I can't just `mv` the contents back to the original directory. I was wondering if there is some kind of *'Trash Explorer'* that lets you see the trash for specific trash directories in it's original hierarchy and lets you restore portions as such.

This time, a memory drive that `Ubuntu One` was using, stopped working. The mount-bind was suddenly empty. `Ubuntu One` proceeded to delete gigabytes of thousands of files on all my computers that shared this directory, luckily putting all the files in a `.Trash` directory locally.

I say again, Nautilus/Nemo does not show this trash, and neither does `trash-list`, yet it is filed with `files`, `info` and `files.u1conflict` courtesy of `Ubuntu One`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Trash-bin dos NOT work right with Bind-Mounts! 
But if the files are there Unhide them and you can drag them out where they belong (after chmod -R g+rwx) with Nautilus or another Gui-filemanager.
Then you have to delete the rest of the files from the terminal.
Hope this works for you.